# goroutine deadlock with waitgroup

Tags: deadlock, goroutine

I was reading through the Go concurrency book, and I came across the following example.

```
func condVarBroadcast() {
        type button struct {
                clicked *sync.Cond
        }
        b := button{sync.NewCond(&sync.Mutex{})}

        // for each call to subscribe, start up a new goroutine
        // and wait using the condition variable.
        subscribe := func(c *sync.Cond, fn func()) {
                var w sync.WaitGroup
                w.Add(1)
                go func() {
                        w.Done()
                        c.L.Lock()
                        defer c.L.Unlock()
                        c.Wait()
                        fn()
                }()
                w.Wait()
        }

        var wg sync.WaitGroup
        wg.Add(3)
        subscribe(b.clicked, func() {
                fmt.Println("Maximize window")
                wg.Done()
        })
        subscribe(b.clicked, func() {
                fmt.Println("displaying dialog box")
                wg.Done()
        })
        subscribe(b.clicked, func() {
                fmt.Println("mouse clicked")
                wg.Done()
        })

        b.clicked.Broadcast()
        wg.Wait()
}
```

I had a couple of doubts:

- if I replace "w.Done()" with "defer w.Done()", there is a deadlock. Why? What is the point of doing `w.Done()` inside a goroutine when it clearly is not done executing? Is this a normal practice?
- Why do we even need to waitgroup `w` in this example? If I don't use it, it says "deadlock: all goroutines are asleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the problem with race condition is that the main is super fast and broadcasts to the `sync.Cond` even before the go-routines start and wait for the lock. The reason to have `w` waitgroup is to make sure that all the go-routines start first and hold the lock before the main thread signals the broadcast

```
func condVarBroadcast() {
        type button struct {
                clicked *sync.Cond
        }
        b := button{sync.NewCond(&sync.Mutex{})}

        // for each call to subscribe, start up a new goroutine
        // and wait using the condition variable.
        subscribe := func(c *sync.Cond, fn func()) {
                var w sync.WaitGroup
                w.Add(1)
                go func() {
                        w.Done() // <-------- this will notify that the goroutine has started
                        c.L.Lock()
                        defer c.L.Unlock()
                        c.Wait()
                        fn()
                }()
                w.Wait() // <--- this will block till the go routine starts and then continue
        }

        var wg sync.WaitGroup
        wg.Add(3)
        subscribe(b.clicked, func() {
                fmt.Println("Maximize window")
                wg.Done()
        })    //    < ----- This call will block till the go routine starts
        subscribe(b.clicked, func() {
                fmt.Println("displaying dialog box")
                wg.Done()
        }) //    < ----- This call will block till the go routine starts
        subscribe(b.clicked, func() {
                fmt.Println("mouse clicked")
                wg.Done()
        }) //    < ----- This call will block till the go routine starts

        b.clicked.Broadcast() // <------------ Once this happens all the go routines will continue the processing
        wg.Wait()
}
```

If you want to avoid the `w` waitgroup, you have to somehow make sure the `Broadcast` call happens after all the go routines start in that case you could add a simple `time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)` before the `Broadcast` call and remove the `w` waitgroup from the code.